# How to Use PreviousPage.FindControl (VB.NET)

Tags: radio-button, findcontrol

i have 2 radiobutton in page1
how to use  this method in page2 ( PreviousPage.FindControl )
so that understand Which selected radiobutton in page 1

Comment: Please read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Answer (score 0):

It's bettor to use below mechanisms for transfer data from page to another:

**Client Side Storage Mechanism:**

- Cookies
- Query String
- Hidden Field (View State)
- Cache

**Server Side Storage Mechanism:**

- Session
- Application

for example in first page you select radiobutton an click on Button or LinkButton,
in button_click event you find selected radiobutton, and put selected data in a querystring variable, then redirect to second page :

> Response.Redirect("~/secondPage.aspx?var=" + data)

In second page read the querystring :

> Request.QueryString["var"]